# Equation to find the work done in lifting $500kg$ of coal from a $350m$ deep mine by a rope that weighs $15N/m$?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question I'm working on is to find the work done in lifting $500kg$ of coal from a $350m$ deep mine by a rope that weighs $15N/m$. Use $g\approx9.81m/s^2$ and I have to express my answer in kilojoules.

After finding that the newton value is $4905 N$, I'm confused on how to get the $F(x)$ equation. The correct answer is $F(x) = 10,155-15x \,N$ but where does the $10,155$ come from? How was that calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help you to draw out a picture of what is going on here, but in effect the total mass being lifted would change, if we look at weight as a function of height raised $F(h)$ then we can see that we have:
$$F(0)=500g+(15\times350)$$
and we can see that:
$$\frac{dF}{dh}=-15$$
now if we integrate we get:
$$F=-15h+C$$
we have already worked out our $C$ as it is our weight at the bottom, so we get:
$$F(h)=500g+(15\times350)-15h$$
now just use the fact that:
$$dW=Fdx$$
or in this case:
$$W=\int Fdh$$